# Core plot graph with grid lines in ios 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-plot

How to get graph shown below in the image using core plot in iOS 8.1.
 I tried for custom labels in x axis

```
 x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
```

But I didn't get how to get the grid lines vertically in the graph?

Help me with this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Add plot space

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace       = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

    plotSpace.delegate              = self;

    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(25)];
```

then change x axis label policy like this

```
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval;
```